# ¿Puedo generar códigos de barra: GS1-128 (UCC/EAN-128) con ReportLab?

Tags: python, reportlab

> Intente con este código pero no genera el formato: GS1-128 (UCC/EAN-128):

```
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import code39, code128, code93

....
....
....

barcode_value = '415'+cCodEan+'8020'+cCodRef+'3900'+cValor+'96'+cFecha
barcode128 = code128.Code128(barcode_value,barWidth=0.013*cm,barHeight=1.5*cm)
barcode128.drawOn(self.canvas, x, y)
```

¿Es posible generar códigos de barras GS-128? En caso afirmativo, ¿cómo debo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

[Aparentemente no](https://pydoc.net/reportlab/3.3.0/reportlab.graphics.barcode/) actualmente, ten en cuenta que code128 y GS1-128 no son lo mismo, aunque éste último está basado en las especificaciones del primero.

Podrías usar el paquete [`barcode`](https://python-barcode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/barcode.html#creating-barcodes-as-image) e incluir la imagen generada en Reportlab:

> python -m pip install barcode

```
import io
from barcode import Gs1_128
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader



fp = io.BytesIO()
Gs1_128("StackOverflowEs", writer=ImageWriter()).write(fp)
fp.seek(0)

width, height = letter
height, width = letter
c = canvas.Canvas("barcode.pdf", pagesize=letter)

c.drawImage(ImageReader(fp), inch, inch * 1)
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Hay más paquetes para Python capaces de generar códigos de barras y Qr, en este caso hago uso de `barcode`  porque actualmente está bien mantenido, soporta GS1 y está bajo licencia permisiva MIT.